# when using BouncyCastle How to customize keyManagerFactory

Tags: bouncycastle

i manage to make a https request with BouncyCastleProvider in order to fit "TLS_ECDHE_ECDSA_WITH_AES_128_CCM_8" cipher suite

```
  Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
            Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleJsseProvider());
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS", BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME);
            KeyManagerFactory keyManagerFactory = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(
                    "PKIX"
                    ,BouncyCastleJsseProvider.PROVIDER_NAME
            );
            KeyStore clientStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
            InputStream instream =Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PFX_PATH);

   sslContext.init(
                        wrapKeyManagers(keyManagerFactory.getKeyManagers()),
                    new TrustManager[]{trustManager},
//                            tmf.getTrustManagers(),
                        SecureRandom.getInstance("DEFAULT", BouncyCastleProvider.PROVIDER_NAME) );
```

and i tring to customize keyManagerFactory in wrapKeyManagers method.

```
private KeyManager[] wrapKeyManagers(KeyManager[] managers) {
    return Arrays.stream(managers)
            .map(manager -> {
                if (manager instanceof X509KeyManager) {
                    X509KeyManager wrappedManager = (X509KeyManager) manager;
                    return new X509KeyManager() {
                        @Override
                        public String[] getClientAliases(String s, Principal[] principals) {
                            return wrappedManager.getClientAliases(replaceRsaWithEc(s), principals);
                        }
```

i find it does not work , i can not run into  these override method

```
@Override
public String[] getClientAliases(String s, Principal[] principals) {
return wrappedManager.getClientAliases(replaceRsaWithEc(s), principals);
}

@Override
 public String chooseClientAlias(String[] strings, Principal[] principals, Socket socket) {
    return wrappedManager.chooseClientAlias(replaceRsaWithEc(strings), principals, socket);
 }

 @Override
 public String[] getServerAliases(String s, Principal[] principals) {
     return wrappedManager.getServerAliases(replaceRsaWithEc(s), principals);
 }
```

I am pretty true this is some thing wrong about BouncyCastle
Is there any api or something to  customize keyManagerFactory?

Badly in need of help

Answer (score 1):

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
            <artifactId>bctls-jdk15on</artifactId>
            <version>1.65</version> 
        </dependency>
```

change the version to 1.64 problem solved